# How to filter an api response with activated routes in Angular9?

Tags: angular

I'm using an API that doesn't have an ID.

> https://api-movies.gateway.linkapi.solutions/v1/movies

I'm using routerlink with a custom route like: `movieDetails/:{{movie.title}}`.

On the page receiving the title, how can I use activated routes to filter only the title response from the url? since i cant filter with param, for example (`movie?title = Whiplash`)

With that I can make the customized page of every detail of the film coming from the api using `{{title}}, {{genre}}` etc

Answer (score 0):

you can get the `url` from `ActivatedRoute`.

maybe there's something like `this.activatedRoute.url`. then split the string by `\` and get the last chunk.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say in your route, **{{movie.Title}}** parameter name is **movieTitle** in **RouterModule** routes array, you can use **snapshot** object on **activatedRoute** service to access the parameter. Something like this

```js
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  let movieTitle = this.route.snapshot.params.movieTitle;

  }
```

Now you can pass this **movieTitle** value to your service, something like

```
this.httpClient.get<any>(`https://api-movies.gateway.linkapi.solutions/v1/movies?title=${movieTitle}`);
```

Thanks.